# Can the stackable trait pattern be used with singleton objects?

Tags: scala, singleton, traits

I'd like to use the [stackable trait pattern](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html) with singleton objects, but i can't seem to find how to make the compiler happy:

```
abstract class Pr {
  def pr()
}

trait PrePostPr extends Pr {
  abstract override def pr() {
    println("prepr")
    super.pr()
    println("postpr")
  }
}

object Foo extends Pr with PrePostPr {
  def pr() = println("Foo")
}
```

Trying to evaluate this in the repl produces the following error:

```
<console>:10: error: overriding method pr in trait PrePostPr of type ()Unit;
 method pr needs `override' modifier
         def pr() = println("Foo")
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It can, but like this:

```
abstract class Pr {
  def pr()
}

trait PrePostPr extends Pr {
  abstract override def pr() {
    println("prepr")
    super.pr()
    println("postpr")
  }
}

class ImplPr extends Pr {
  def pr() = println("Foo")
}

object Foo extends ImplPr with PrePostPr
```

The implementation has to be present in one of the superclasses/supertraits. The abstract modification trait has to come after the class/trait with the implementation in the inheritance list.

Comment: It appears it's fine to use the same name, so i can name the class "Foo" and then have object "Foo" extend class "Foo".

Comment: Yes, it is - in that case the object `Foo` is called the companion object of the class `Foo`.