# Using stackable trait with singleton object

Tags: scala, singleton, traits

my case is a bit similar to this question:

[Can the stackable trait pattern be used with singleton objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499680/can-the-stackable-trait-pattern-be-used-with-singleton-objects)

but with small difference. What I have can be simplified to the below form:

```
abstract class Pr {
  def pr()
}

trait PrePostPr extends Pr {
  var NUMERIC_VAR: Int = _
  abstract override def pr() {
    NUMERIC_VAR = 5 // number is being extracted eg. from conf file
    super.pr()
  }
}
```

Now I would really like to have a singleton object that will check the constant and depending on it would take some further action in a following way:

```
class ImplPr extends Pr with PrePostPr {
  def pr() = if(NUMERIC_VAR > 5) println("Foo") else println("Bar")
}

object Foo extends ImplPr
Foo.pr()
```

Unfortunatelly, the above code does not compile - I get:

> method pr needs `override' modifier

Is there any workaround to make this solution work?

Comment: I don't think this is conceptually possible. In order for `Foo.pr` to access `NUMERIC_VAR`, it has to be implemented in a class which is a subclass of `PrePostPr`, which in turn means that it will never be called as `super.pr()` in `PrePostPr.pr()`. You probably have to move `NUMERIC_VAR` to a different class/trait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would work if you move `NUMERIC_VAR` to a different trait:

```
  trait NumericVarHolder {
    var NUMERIC_VAR: Int = _
  }

  abstract class Pr {
    def pr()
  }

  trait PrePostPr extends Pr {
    self: NumericVarHolder =>
    abstract override def pr() {
      NUMERIC_VAR = 5 // number is being extracted eg. from conf file
      super.pr()
    }
  }

  class ImplPr extends Pr with NumericVarHolder {
    def pr() = if(NUMERIC_VAR > 5) println("Foo") else println("Bar")
  }

  object Foo extends ImplPr
```